# How to remove a particular image URL from disk cache in Glide?

Tags: android, image, caching, android-glide

I am loading an image from remote `URL` into an `ImageView` with Glide. When I update the image, the content within that URL changes, but the URL location remains same. (This is as expected).

for eg. `https://www.the-android-app.com/userid/121.jpg`

Now I am showing image into ImageView using this code.

```
Glide
     .with(this)
     .load(profilePicUrl) //this is in String format
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .error(R.drawable.default_profile_pic)
     .into(imgProfilePic);
```

When I update my profile pic, Glide is loading the same old pic from `Cache`. I need to remove cache entry for this `URL` before fetching the new image.

**Edit:**
The url always remains same, only the content inside it changes.
I'm using Glide 3.8.0

Comment: the url changes or not ?

Comment: The url remains same all the time.

Comment: which vesion of glide you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try  **signature(new ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))**

Look in [Custom cache invalidation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation#custom-cache-invalidation) for more information.

**Example**

```
GlideApp.with(this)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .signature(new ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .into(imageView);
```